# Spring Boot OAuth2 and UserDetails

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement an Auth server for my REST API in Spring Boot and I am struggling to autowire my own user repository into the the configuration. Could someone suggest how to do this correctly?

I have the following auth server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${gigsterous.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
    private int expiration;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        configurer.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("gigsterous")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .resourceIds("resource");
    }

    /**
     * Use custom jwt token converter to enhance the token with custom fields
     *
     * @return CustomTokenConverter
     */
    @Bean
    public CustomTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new CustomTokenConverter();
    }
}
```

User service:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return (UserDetails) userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    protected User() {
        // hibernate
    }

}
```

I am using Flyway and currently storing my users in H2 in memory database (this is working correctly so I omit this part of code from my question to avoid confusion).

When I try to authorise some user from my database using this command:

```
curl -X POST --user 'gigsterous:secret' -d 'grant_type=password&username=peter&password=password' http://localhost:9000/gigsterous-auth/oauth/token
```

I get the following response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"com.gigsterous.auth.domain.User cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails"}
```

Apparently, I cannot covert my user POJO into `UserDetails` object but I cannot figure out how to construct it correctly since it is an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been long time I've not worked on Spring, my memory might be not good. But if I'm not wrong, you want to use your User as UserDetails, you have to implement it, UserDetails is an interface. :D
And I recommend to change name of your class, User is already existed in OAuth2 library